# How do I run a php code string from Python?

Tags: php, python

I've found that you can run a php file from Python by using this:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen('php.exe input.php', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
response = proc.stdout.read().decode("utf-8")
print(response)
```

But is there a way to run php code from a string, not from a file? For example:

```
<?php
  $a = ['a', 'b', 'c'][0];
  echo($a);
?>
```

Comment: Yes. PHP can run code from stdin.

Comment: Can you demonstrate?

Comment: Check out the `-r --run` command line flag on http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT]

Use `php -r "code"` with *subprocess.Popen*:

```
def php(code):
    p = subprocess.Popen(["php", "-r", code],
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out = p.communicate() #returns a tuple (stdoutdata, stderrdata)
    if out[1] != b'': raise Exception(out[1].decode('UTF-8'))
    return out[0].decode('UTF-8')

code = """ \
  $a = ['a', 'b', 'c'][2]; \
  echo($a);"""
print(php(code))
```

[Original Answer]

I found a [simple class](https://github.com/brool/util/blob/master/php.py) that allows you to do that.
The code is self-explanatory. The class contains 3 methods:

> - get_raw(self, code): Given a code block, invoke the code and return the raw result as a string
> - get(self, code): Given a code block that emits json, invoke the code and interpret the result as a Python value.
> - get_one(self, code): Given a code block that emits multiple json values (one per line), yield the next value.

The example you wrote would look like this:

```
php = PHP()
code = """ \
  $a = ['a', 'b', 'c'][0]; \
  echo($a);"""
print (php.get_raw(code))
```

You can also add a prefix and postfix to the code with `PHP(prefix="",postfix"")`

PS.: I modified the original class because popen2 is deprecated. I also made the code compatible with Python 3. You can [get it here](https://gist.github.com/victortv7/e5b30bf5aff71c9511d98f77c9bfb1be) :

```
import json
import subprocess

class PHP:
    """This class provides a stupid simple interface to PHP code."""

    def __init__(self, prefix="", postfix=""):
        """prefix = optional prefix for all code (usually require statements)
        postfix = optional postfix for all code
        Semicolons are not added automatically, so you'll need to make sure to put them in!"""
        self.prefix = prefix
        self.postfix = postfix

    def __submit(self, code):
        code = self.prefix + code + self.postfix
        p = subprocess.Popen(["php","-r",code], shell=True,
                  stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        (child_stdin, child_stdout) = (p.stdin, p.stdout)
        return child_stdout

    def get_raw(self, code):
        """Given a code block, invoke the code and return the raw result as a string."""
        out = self.__submit(code)
        return out.read()

    def get(self, code):
        """Given a code block that emits json, invoke the code and interpret the result as a Python value."""
        out = self.__submit(code)
        return json.loads(out.read())

    def get_one(self, code):
        """Given a code block that emits multiple json values (one per line), yield the next value."""
        out = self.__submit(code)
        for line in out:
            line = line.strip()
            if line:
                yield json.loads(line)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I found two problems, however, but neither are serious. With `close_fds=True` included I get the error `ValueError: close_fds is not supported on Windows platforms if you redirect stdin/stdout/stderr`, but with that removed it runs fine. Then I still get the output in bytes with `b` at the beginning. So I just added `.decode("utf-8")` to the print statement, like in my first example. If you make those changes to the answer it will be more helpful.

Comment: Also, the functions `get` and `get_one` are unneeded for this example, and so could be removed for brevity.

Comment: From what [I've read](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor):  
"Note that on Windows, you cannot set close_fds to true and also redirect the standard handles by setting stdin, stdout or stderr."  
I realized that it was working for me because I am using [python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html): "Changed in version 3.7: It’s now possible to set close_fds to True when redirecting the standard handles"

Comment: Is there any advantage of using close_fds?

Comment: I think it's better to leave out close_fds and let the *subprocess* decide what is best according to your OS and python version. Also, reading the docs I could note that it recommends using shell=False to avoid code injection and using the method communicate() instead of read() when you use stdout=PIPE.
stdin is also not necessary if you don't need to send a streaming input. I've edited my post to include a much simpler version. I've added exception handling though, which was made easier with *communicate()*

Answer (score 1):

Based on Victor Val's answer, here is my own compact version.

```
import subprocess

def run(code):
    p = subprocess.Popen(['php','-r',code], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    return p.stdout.read().decode('utf-8')

code = """ \
  $a = ['a', 'b', 'c'][0]; \
  echo($a);"""
print(run(code))
```